# How To Right Align Image Inside Input Field?

Tags: html, css

How do I right align a JPEG image inside an input field?

```
.input-field {  
    background: #fff url("../images/search.jpg") no-repeat; 
}
```

By default, the image is left aligned.

Comment: When using left aligned icon, you can fine tune its position, but in right aligned one you can't. Also using absolute position value reduce your reusability for input different widths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add "right"

```
.input-field {  
    background: #fff url("../images/search.jpg") no-repeat right; 
}
```

More informations about background position: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use background position:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

```
.input-field {  
    background: #fff url("../images/search.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

Comment: The property `background` is able to hold all possible combinations of `background-*` parameters, theres no need to be redundant and use both.

Answer (score 1):

you can also specify the position in pixels or percentage

background-position: 20px center;

Comment: In case the width is undefined, your solution is not universal.